# mysql login username password

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, passwords

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "csc4370FA14_18";
$password = "1db23";
$dbname = "csc4370FA14_18";


$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$username_login = $_POST["username"];
$password_login = $_POST["pw"];

$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$username_login'");
$numrow = mysql_num_rows($query2);

if ($numrow != 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2)) {
        $dbusername = $row['name'];
        $dbpassword = $row['password'];
    }

    // Check to see if username and password match
    if ($username_login==$dbusername && $password_login==$dbpassword) {
        echo "You are in";
    }
    else {
        echo "Sorry $username_login. Incorrect password!";
    }
}
```

This is the code I am using to check if a user matches the password (same row) in a table.
I am getting the error:

> Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user 'apache'@'localhost'
> (using password: NO) in
> /home/csc4370FA14_18/public_html/program/assignments/group
> project3/login.php on line 14 Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the
> server could not be established in
> /home/csc4370FA14_18/public_html/program/assignments/group
> project3/login.php on line 14 Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects
> parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
> /home/csc4370FA14_18/public_html/program/assignments/group
> project3/login.php on line 15

I have not a clue why this might be incorrect as the login credentials, etc work fine. I think it has something to do with mysqli, but I don't have a very good grasp of this versus the mysql_* functions. I know for a fact this is the correct connect info.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

Answer (score -1):

Try this code.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "csc4370FA14_18";
$password = "1db23";
$dbname = "csc4370FA14_18";


$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$username_login = $_POST["username"];
$password_login = $_POST["pw"];

$query2 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$username_login'");
$numrow = mysqli_num_rows($query2);

if ($numrow != 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)) {
        $dbusername = $row['name'];
        $dbpassword = $row['password'];
    }

    // Check to see if username and password match
    if ($username_login==$dbusername && $password_login==$dbpassword) {
        echo "You are in";
    }
    else {
        echo "Sorry $username_login. Incorrect password!";
    }
}
```